# Cassandra (phpcassa) reversed keys?

Tags: php, nosql, cassandra, phpcassa

I know i can reverse the column order like:

> $rows = $test->get_range("", "", 10, NULL, "", "", true);

But keys are in db like 1, 2, 3, 4
I want to get the latest 10 keys, and then do like reverse paging.
So i basically want first in first out.
What would be the best method?

Sure I could get all the keys out of cassandra and then reverse them by php but there must be something more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using RandomPartition (which you almost certainly should be, see [here for more info on picking a partitioner](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/cluster_architecture/partitioning#understanding-the-partitioner-types)), you cannot get an ordered range of keys.  Even if you're using an OrderedPartitioner, there's no way to get a range of keys in reverse.

To achieve what you're trying to do, use rows where the column names are what you are currently using for row keys, and simply get a reversed slice of columns with limit 10.